# Better way to initialize python ctypes structure field

Tags: python, initialization, ctypes

Is there a better way to initialize a ctypes field that is meant to be static/constant than what I have below?

```
from ctypes import *

class foo(LittleEndianStructure):
  _fields_ = [
    ("signature", c_ulonglong),
    ]

  def __init__(self):
      super(LittleEndianStructure,self).__init__()
      self.signature = 0x896489648964

f = foo()
print hex(f.signature)
```

For example, I was hoping I could do something similar to how you could do it with a normal python object:

```
class bar:
    signature = 0x896489648964

b = bar()
print hex(b.signature)
```

Comment: That should be `super(foo, self).__init__(0x896489648964)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no, you can't do this, and shouldn't want to.

---

Your normal Python object sample doesn't do what you think. It's not automatically initializing an instance attribute; it's creating a class attribute instead.

They work similarly in some cases, but they're not the same thing. For example, compare:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     bar=[]
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.baz=[]
... 
>>> f1 = Foo()
>>> f2 = Foo()
>>> f1.bar.append(100)
>>> f1.baz.append(100)
>>> f2.bar
[100]
>>> f2.baz
[]
```

Here, `f1` and `f2` each initialize their own `baz`, but they do *not* automatically initialize their own `bar`—they share a single `bar` with every other instance.

And, more directly relevant to this case:

```
>>> f1.__dict__
{'baz': [1]}
```

The `bar` class attribute is not part of `f1`'s dictionary.

So, translating the same thing to `ctypes`, your `"signature"` would not be a member of your structure if you made it a class attribute—that is, it wouldn't be laid out in memory as part of each instance. Which would defeat the entire purpose of having it.

---

If you know C++, it may help to look at it in C++ terms.

A class attribute, like `bar` above, is sort of* like a static member variable in C++, while an instance attribute is like a normal instance member variable.

In this C++ code:

```
struct bar {
    static const long signature = 0x896489648964;
};
```

… each `bar` is actually an empty structure; there's a single `bar::signature` stored somewhere else in memory. You can reference it through `bar` instances, but only because the compiler turns `b1.signature` into `bar::signature`.

---

* The reason I say "sort of" is that Python class attributes can be overridden by subclasses, while C++ static members can't, they really are just global variables, and they can only be "hidden" by subclasses.